# Using python to run command on a specific extension file from a folder and moves it to another folder after it's done

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dataframe, etl

I am trying to create a python file that would:

1. Look for a csv file from a folder(Incomplete).
2. Run some commands on that csv file,let say extract that csv data to a python list.
3. Moves that csv to a new folder(Complete).

And this is needed to be done recursively, script must run when it finds a new file is available in that folder(Incomplete).

```
import os
import csv
for filename in os.listdir('C:\Users\Zaibi\Desktop'):
    with open("'"+filename+"'") as f:
        data = csv.DictReader(f)
        for n in data:
            print n
```

I'm fairly new to python, so unaware of the modules required for this job

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service... And usually questions have a "?" mark. Your question isn't even a question.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @Dot_Py , To start with I am unable to find a module that will work in my case, I have tried using glob, os , subprocess. But couldn't got through, or may be I am using them wrong.

Comment: @pyNoob Thanks, man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using excel. You should be able to figure out how to change it to CSV  ;)

```
import pandas as pd
import os

source_directory = r'H:\folder'

master_list = []

for file in os.listdir(source_directory):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx") or file.endswith(".xls") or file.endswith(".xlsm") or file.endswith(".xlsb"):
        dataframe = pd.read_excel(source_directory + '\\' + file)
        master_list.append(dataframe)

masterDF = pd.concat(master_list, ignore_index=True)
print(masterDF)
```